# Is it still possible to get the Tumbler Sparrow?

Tags: destiny

There's a fancy sparrow that was earned by preordering *The Dark Below* expansion before a certain date (January something).

I still see a lot of people riding it around, but I only recently picked up the season pass for the DLC.  Is there still some way I can unlock it, or was it *exclusively* available for that promotion?

Comment: You could also purchase that Sparrow through the Special Orders shop in the Tower (near the Postmaster). No idea if it is still sold there.

Comment: @finLprtoTyp - You cannot "purchase" them there though. If you have unlocked them through preordering the expansion then they are available there for you to pick up for free on every character that you have. But you will not see anything there if you did not unlock them. The same with special shaders and emblems (for example from the beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Currently the only way to get the Tumbler Sparrow is if you purchased The Dark Below (or the Expansion Pass) before mid January 2015.